# Распределение потоков по ядрам процессора

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Если я создаю два потока в системе с двумя ядрами, я могу быть уверен, что они не попадут на одно ядро или хотя бы не попадут на одно виртуальное ядро (сейчас я говорю про hyper threading). И если нет, то могу ли я вообще как-то повлиять на это? Или ОС сделает все за меня наилучшим образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На это можно повлиять, например в WinAPI при помощи функции [SetThreadAffinityMask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Но обычно это не нужно, ОС сама все распределит наилучшим образом.